# REST / JSON API [Help]

Tags: json, rest

I'm (Attempting) to make a game in the UnrealEngine and i have finally managed to find a way to save to a server in the form of REST or JSON.

here is the problem... i have NO IDEA what they are

i know (I think) that JSON is a variant of Java and REST is a variant of HTTP (Don't hold it to me) i think i have to layer the request via a HTML page or something similar. through my countless hours of Google searching i seam to be missing key information.

an example of what I'm trying to do is get my game server to send a "user","Pass" via JSON/REST to a NonSQL Database of some variant via a web page? and have the server send the request back?

I'm not looking to learn Java or anything as such I'm just trying to find out what I need to make the DB/Web interface and how I send/receive to and from it.

I think im probably clutching at straws here but i am out of ideas and cant seam to find a conclusive answer that does not have so much technical jargon that my brain gets a virus, I'm not a dim wit I've dealt with SQL, C++ and WAMP and Apache and on and on but I just cant find what I'm looking for.

if someone could help I would hugely appreciate it as this is bottlenecking my progress

Thanks Guys!

EDIT:: Tried using RestX however i receive this error when trying to compile my app

```
ggo-app> app compile
javac: invalid flag: target\dependency/classmate-0.8.0.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
compiling App... [5 source files] [ERROR]
```

i don't think i have the brains for this, may be in over my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, JSON isn't a variant of Java. This is a data format.

> I'm not looking to learn Java or anything as such I'm just trying to find out what I need to make the DB/Web interface and how I send/receive to and from it.

You can try to use REST API framework such as [Casablanca](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/) or [Restx](http://restx.io/)

Comment: yeh sorry, i forgot is a string wrapper, derped in the moment... thanks when i get back from the shop ima spend a few hrs blindly looking the the links :P thanks

Comment: @GrantReed feel free to ask questions if they appear :)

Comment: i tried to install Restx however i get "compiling App... [ERROR]" and the application failed to start  (ScreenShot http://prntscr.com/6xibir) and i dont understand Casablanca it appears to just be VS Library?